# Whoops & Laravel 4.1.26

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, whoops

I recently upgraded to 4.1.26 on my local machine and now it seems that whoops isnt working correctly. All I am getting at the moment is a blank screen with a title as seen below, can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

http://imageshack.com/a/img841/820/tpcm.png

Comment: Have you tried turning Debug on in `app/config/app.php`?

Comment: @ajtrichards_wales I always thought it was set to true by default...doh! thank you that has resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what's wrong with your application until you at least **enable debugging**.

As a first guess though, it might be the new remember_token that was introduced in 4.1.26. A lot of people are having issues adjusting to it.

Have you updated your User model yet? If not, open:

```
app/models/User.php
```

and add the following methods:

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

Then, add a new column called *remember_token* (of type *VARCHAR(100)*, *TEXT*, or whatever equivalent you want) to your *users* table. **It must be nullable**.

Finally, when you're ready to authenticate a user, just add *true* as the second argument to *attempt* method.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
{
    // At this point the user is remembered
}
```

That's it. Hope this solves your issue. Happy coding!

Source: [Laravel Upgrade Guide](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26)

Comment: A comment on the question shows that the topic starter has resolved this issue 20hours ago.